# apply() method syntax in groovy

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, closures

In the below syntax:

```
plugins({
  id('application')
  id 'java'
  id('com.github.johnrengelman.shadow').version('4.0.1')
})
allprojects(
  {
    apply(plugin: 'application')
    apply(plugin: 'java')
    apply(plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow')

    repositories({
      mavenCentral()
    })
  }
  ....

  task copyDeps(type: Copy) {
      from (configurations.runtime + configurations.testRuntime) exclude '*'
      into '/tmp'
  } 
)
```

---

my understanding is,

`apply()` method is passing key-value `plugin: 'application'`, where key is `plugin` & value is `'application'`

From the syntax aspect of `apply()` method, `plugin: 'application'` is not a readable syntax:

1) How do I understand this syntax `apply(plugin: 'application')`? Is `plugin: 'application'` an argument of type `String` passed through method `apply()`?

2)

Below  syntax

```
task copyDeps(type: Copy) {  // Line 54
          from (configurations.runtime + configurations.testRuntime) exclude '*'
          into '/tmp'
      }
```

is written as

```
tasks.create('copyDeps', Copy, { 
                                from(configurations.runtime + configurations.testRuntime).exclude('*')
                                into(buildDir)
                                }
            )
```

but gives error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/../build.gradle' line: 54
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an idiomatic groovy "shortcutting".

The line

```
apply(plugin: 'application')
```

can be rewritten as:

```
apply( [ plugin: 'application' ] )
```

and means, that the `apply()` method is called with a Groovy Map literal. 
Map literal replaces java's:

```
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put( "plugin", "application" );
```

If a method as the last argument accepts a map, the square brackets can be omitted.

The line can also be rewritten as:

```
apply plugin:'application'
```

with no brackets at all.

UPDATE:

2nd question:

yes it can (if it compiles). It looks ugly but valid.

In Groovy if method's last argument is a closure, it can be written either as

```
copyDeps( map ){ }
```

or

```
copyDeps map, {}
```

or (more javaish)

```
copyDeps( map, {} )
```

UPDATE 2:

`tasks.create('copyDeps', Copy, {})` and `task copyDeps(type: Copy) {}` are also interchangeable this time in Gradle as per [ref-doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:defining_tasks).

The `tasks.create()` is a plain method call on a class property, whereas `task copyDeps()` represents another Groovy capability: the DSL Builders -> here Gradle DSL builder is used.

Comment: Query edited, Can you please answer the second question?